# How to set a custom RedirectUri in com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver

Tags: java, google-api, google-oauth, google-sheets-api, google-oauth-java-client

I'm developing a java application that integrates with google API (google sheets API)

I'm trying to follow an example provided in google developers website. Link: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/java#step_3_set_up_the_sample

They have used LocalServerReceiver to create the redirect uri as below.

`LocalServerReceiver receiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(8888).build();`

It is being used inside com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp => authorize() method like this:

`String redirectUri = receiver.getRedirectUri();`

This is how receiver.getRedirectUri() generates the uri:

```
public String getRedirectUri() throws IOException {

    server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(port != -1 ? port : findOpenPort()), 0);
    HttpContext context = server.createContext(callbackPath, new CallbackHandler());
    server.setExecutor(null);

    try {
      server.start();
      port = server.getAddress().getPort();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      Throwables.propagateIfPossible(e);
      throw new IOException(e);
    }
    return "http://" + this.getHost() + ":" + port + callbackPath;
}
```

Since I'm running this in localhost, getRedirectUri() returns a url like this:

http://localhost:8888/Callback

What I want is to provide a custom url since I'm using ngrok to expose my localhost.

Ex: If I visit the url "paradise.au.ngrok.io" that will point to my localhost.

So I need to pass "paradise.au.ngrok.io" as redirect url.

Can someone help me out to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use the [`setHost()`](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-oauth-client/1.30.1/com/google/api/client/extensions/jetty/auth/oauth2/LocalServerReceiver.Builder.html#setHost-java.lang.String-) method and set the redirect URI to your ngrok one.